# Laravel: How do I make route helper return urls with trailing slashes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How do I make Laravel 5.3 create route URLs with trailing slashes?

The route is defined as

```
 Route::get('/home/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
```

I then create the url with the route helper function in a view:

```
{{ route('home') }}
```

This creates `http://localhost:8000/home` instead of `http://localhost:8000/home/`.

This question is very similar to [Laravel - append a trailing slash in routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285947/laravel-append-a-trailing-slash-in-routes), but that question doesn't have an answer either and it seems to me that my description is a tat shorter.

Edit:
The two possible naming methods from the docs don't make a difference:

```
Route::get('/home/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
Route::get('/home/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: what happen when you access the one with trailing slash? afaik it will redirect to somewhere else. one of its solution is [this so answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21735548/4648586)

Comment: As long as the webserver doesn't redirect laravel will respond to the request.

Comment: it something had to do with the [`.htaccess`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess#L10). as it discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441338/laravel-5-bad-behaviour-while-removing-trailing-slash) you had to edit your `.htaccess` in public directory. although... [in a certain discussion](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/58#issuecomment-12367008)

Comment: I had a deep look at the `UrlGenerator` and I thought of extending it for this purpose, namely changing its `format()` method, which strips the trailing slash. Unfortunately, I realized that Laravel is not flexible enough with it, so doing it in a fancy way is not possible. Laravel even registers some magic on `UrlGenerator` during runtime right after registering the `UrlGenerator` itself. This feature is pretty badly designed, to be honest. So your only chance is to create your own helper (or overwrite existing `route()` helper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Laravel will remove slash at the end of URL so you just can do it by using `{{ route('home') }}/`.

Reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L308-L345

Comment: or create your own [helper method](http://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2015-best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1)

Answer (score 1):

The marked variant is more similar to a crutch than to the decision as URL is in **sitemap.xml** and still anywhere therefore in this case, it is better to edit everything only in the directory **routes/*.php**, That is all same the variant with `UrlGenerator` census will be the most correct. In this case, there is a very useful [package](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminatech/url-trailing-slash) (`illuminatech/url-trailing-slash`) that essentially should solve this problem. All changes will be only at the routing level.